# MultipartFile to Blob : Spring Boot configuration for hibernate session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, blob

I'm trying to add an image into a Blob of my MySQL databases.

I'm using Spring Boot for the backend and AngularJs for the frontend.

So, **AngularJs** send to my RestController :

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", this.credentials.avatar);

$http.post(
    '/register-user-blob', 
    fd,
    {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }
)
```

Then, my **@RestController** receive a Spring MultipartFile :

```
import java.sql.Blob;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
//[...others imports]

@RestController
public class RegisterRest {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register-user-blob", produces = "application/json")
    public FormRegisterResponseDto registerUserWithBlob(@RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file){

        Blob avatar = null;

        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename()); // It works so I receive the MultipartFile correctly.
        System.out.println(sessionFactory); // It works, so SessionFactory is not null

        try {
            avatar = Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob(file.getInputStream(),file.getSize());
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ...
        }

        try{
            // try to insert into databases
        } catch (Exception ex){
            // ...
        }

        return new FormRegisterResponseDto();
    }

}
```

As you see, I'm using org.hibernate.Hibernate.getLobCreator(...) to cast my MultipartFile to java.sql.Blob
This method needs Hibernate Session so I configure Spring Boot for it (if I understand, Spring Boot initialize a JPA Session so I must to configure it to get a Hibernate Session) :

my **application.properties** :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

my **Spring Boot config class**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BusinessBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusinessBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

So, I don't understand why I have this error :

**org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread**

Do you have an idea please ? Thanks :)

Comment: Why that ugly contraption... Just use the `EntityManager`, annotate a `byte[]` type field in the entity your are storing with `@Lob` and let JPA handle it for you. Don't make it as complex as you do.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :/

Comment: JPA can perfectly handle BLOBs... No need to do the ugly stuff with hibernate just use plain JPA instead.

Comment: Ok. So instead of use @Lob private Blob avatar; in my class entity, you advice me to use Lob private byte[] avatar; ?

Comment: So, if I replace Blob by byte[] in my model, how I can doing the request in my RestController ? For the moment I receive a MultipartFile, do you thinks that angularJs can send byte[] ? thx

Comment: No. Just transform the input stream to a byte[]...

Comment: Ok thanks :) I will try it :)

Comment: How does the @Lob / byte[] handle _large_ files? When someone uploads a 1G file, I would prefer not to instantiate that in memory.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387554) will be helpful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387554