# How to stream data to MariaDB over JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, blob, mariadb

I want to store BLOB data into `MariaDB` using `MariaDB` connector and I try to find the most efficient solution. Now I'm using `setBlob()` or `setBinaryStream()` method to store data. But it is so slow comparing to direct streaming of data to database. I used streaming for Oracle database and everything worked fast and perfectly. But since I changed the database to `MariaDB`, direct streaming doesn't work.

The code for direct streaming is the following:

```
        Blob localBlob =  lrs.getBlob("MyData");

        try {
            los = localBlob.setBinaryStream(1);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
        int countBytesRead;
        // md5 hash
        InputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(inputStreamArgument, localHash);
        byte[] localBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((countBytesRead = dis.read(localBuffer)) >= 0) {
            los.write(localBuffer, 0, countBytesRead);
        }
        los.close();
        inputStreamArgument.close();
        lstmt.close();
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question if there is a possibility how to store BLOB data into MariaDB by using another method rather than storing BLOB data by using setBlob() or setBinaryStream() methods. And it should be much more efficient than the previous one.

Comment: your example is not complete. what is an lrs?

Comment: It is ResultSet instance

Answer (score 1):

Short answer  - you cannot stream blobs as of today. this connector always reads at least one entire row into memory. Moreover, the MariaDB Server( and MySQL as well) does not handle blobs very efficiently, it also would load the entire blog into memory, only on the server side. If you want do-it-yourself streaming, maybe you can split the blob into smaller chunks of say 4K, and store them in different rows in a dedicated table. you can SELECT * from my_blob to read that as multiple rows, and use e.g setFetchSize(1) to read one chunk at a time.

Comment: I have more than 4M data in my table, dividing the data into small chunks will increase this number.

Comment: if you divide 4M in 4K chunks, number of chunks will be 1K. But 4M is not a big deal really, allocating that amount of memory is not problematic. If you need several GB blobs, then lack of streaming may be more painful.

Comment: I have just tried to split blob into smaller chunks and the performance during the insert operation became 2x worse than it was before... OFFTOP: please, add me on Facebook, I have already sent you the request.

Comment: 4M _rows_?  Or 4M _bytes in table?  Or 4M _bytes in a blob_?

Comment: @RickJames, one blog of size 4MB

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that inserting or selecting a 4MB `BLOB` is more than a small hiccup.  Sure, the data needs to be copied twice if there is no streaming.  But 2 times a small time is still a pretty small time.  How much time are you talking about?

Comment: It is just an example to give the rough idea of how it may look like. 4MB blob is probably fine. 1GB blob is probably not, especially if application is having multiple concurrent JDBC connection, then 1GB should be split. One could experiment with chunk sizes to find a compromise. the problem we're trying to handle here is just preventing OOMs on either side of connection.