# how to extract data from ElementCollection

Tags: database, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to extract data from an ElementCollection that is contained in StandartFont.

```
public class DBFonts {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String nameFont;


@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name="StandartFont",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Fonts_id")
@Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(length=100000)
private List<byte[]> StandartFonts; }
```

Repository:

```
public interface FontRepo extends JpaRepository<DBFonts,Long> {
   List<byte[]> findByStandartFonts(Long fonsId);
}

 HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Hibernate: alter table font add constraint FKpcplr5ixrmh5lbjx0e6peoqo4 foreign key (user_id) references usr (id)
Hibernate: alter table standart_font add constraint FKq7nxy6see56tp2y997fwmsewq foreign key (fonts_id) references font (id)
2018-12-06 16:15:54.338  INFO 6168 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-06 16:15:54.884  WARN 6168 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addFont': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fontRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fontRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List spring_mvc.entity.FontRepo.findByStandartFonts(java.lang.Long)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [standartFonts] on this ManagedType [spring_mvc.entity.DBFonts]
2018-12-06 16:15:54.884  INFO 6168 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-06 16:15:54.886  INFO 6168 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-12-06 16:15:54.896  INFO 6168 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-12-06 16:15:54.898  INFO 6168 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-12-06 16:15:54.916  INFO 6168 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2018-12-06 16:15:54.928 ERROR 6168 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addFont': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fontRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fontRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List spring_mvc.entity.FontRepo.findByStandartFonts(java.lang.Long)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [standartFonts] on this ManagedType [spring_mvc.entity.DBFonts]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fontRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List spring_mvc.entity.FontRepo.findByStandartFonts(java.lang.Long)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [standartFonts] on this ManagedType [spring_mvc.entity.DBFonts]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
```

It does not work, how to extract data correctly?

**Will it work?:**
select standart_fonts  FROM standart_font where fonts_id=?
How to write this in @Query

Comment: Can you expand on *It does not work*?

Comment: Please rename field 'StandartFonts' to 'standartFonts'

Comment: WARN 8412 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [[B (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [[B (n/a)]

Comment: Can you give full stacktrace?

Comment: It's full!!!!!!

Comment: try to use `List<Blob>` instead of `List<byte[]>`

Comment: example: [spring-data-jpa-storing-blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469136/spring-data-jpa-storing-blob)

Comment: It's still a mistake

Comment: I wrote intellig:DBFonts' domain type or valid projection interface expected here.

Answer (score 1):

Spring cant find attribute with name `standartFonts` in your class `DBFonts` and that's why it can't create been with your `repository`

> Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [standartFonts] on
>   this ManagedType [spring_mvc.entity.DBFonts]

Spring using reflection get method name (`findByStandartFonts`) from your repository and parse it: `findBy` its means `select` and `StandartFonts` spring parse as `standartFonts` and it try to find this field in your `@Entity`

PS. In `id` field, please, use `Long` instead of `long`. It's good practice.
And use `camelCase` in your java code...

Comment: WARN 8412 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [[B (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [[B (n/a)]